# compare two wide character strings visual c++

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, wchar-t

I need to compare two wide character strings in c++.

```
wchar_t *str1 = L"abc";
wchar_t *str2 = L"abc";
```

How to compare two wchar_t* variables?

Comment: Fyi, your only two sentences in this question ask different questions. The former is answered below.The latter is trivial (`str1 == str2`), but I doubt that was your intention.

Answer (score 4):

use [wcscmp()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wcscmp/) to compare wide character strings.

```
wchar_t *str1 = L"abc";
wchar_t *str2 = L"abc";

if (wcscmp(str1,str2) == 0)
    cout << "str1 and str2 are Equal";
```